# Are "Glue" records in DNS used only by nameservers of the same domain?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am bit confused with where  "***Glue record***" is used in DNS.

[This](http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/articles/glue_records) documents say

> If you are using someone else's name servers (eg. your ISP's), you
>   won't need to worry about glue records. You only need to worry about
>   glue records when you are configuring your own name servers where a
>   circular reference exists.

And so `Glue` record will be present only for nameservers which are within the domain for which they are authoritative for. i.e they are required if example.com has nameserver as ns1.example.com and it will not be required if it is on another domain.

Based on [this](http://www.barryodonovan.com/2011/02/16/querying-for-dns-glue-records) document I use `dig` command to see if glue records are present for domains which have nameserver hosted in another domain. And surprisingly they too have glue records !. I am trying to see if `novanext.com` has glue record as their nameservers are in different domain.

**Updated**

```
$ dig ns com.
;; ANSWER SECTION:
com.            85916   IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            85916   IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            85916   IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            85916   IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
....
```

And next getting the "glue" record of `novanext.com` domain.

```
$ dig ns novanext.com @g.gtld-servers.net.

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> ns novanext.com @g.gtld-servers.net.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55040
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 6
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;novanext.com.          IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
novanext.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns2.net4india.com.
novanext.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns1.net4india.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.net4india.com.  172800  IN  A   202.71.131.12
ns2.net4india.com.  172800  IN  A   202.71.131.13
ns2.net4india.com.  172800  IN  A   202.71.131.241
ns1.net4india.com.  172800  IN  A   202.71.128.222
ns1.net4india.com.  172800  IN  A   202.71.128.37
ns1.net4india.com.  172800  IN  A   202.71.129.33

;; Query time: 279 msec
```

How is this possible ? I have googled a lot but still not able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't actually see the glue record for `airbnb.in` in your output? All I see is IPV4 and IPV6 glue records for the domains that the servers are indeed authorative for.

Comment: yes absolutely, glue records are IPV4 or IPV6 address of nameservers and [this](http://faq.domainmonster.com/dns/glue_record/) document also says so. Do domain names have `glue` record ?

Comment: @Yaalie Reaces is correct, actually. Look closely at the left side of the `AUTHORITY` section. That's a referral for `in.`, not `airbnb.in.`. You asked for `airbnb.in.`, but were given a referral to the nameservers for `in.` because they are the most specific nameservers that root is aware of. `dig +trace +additional airbnb.in` would show you the full referral chain, glue records included.

Comment: @AndrewB and Reaces sorry for wrongly pasting the output. I have updated the `dig` output in my question section. Please refer it

Comment: @Yaalie Okay, that makes much more sense. I've submitted an answer that should explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And so Glue record will be present only for nameservers which are within the domain for which they are authoritative for. i.e they are required if example.com has nameserver as ns1.example.com and it will not be required if it is on another domain.

Sadly, this is an incorrect conclusion to draw. There's nothing to stop you from serving glue records that aren't strictly necessary. Let's say that I operate the nameservers for `example.com`, and I want to delegate `sub.example.com` to `ns1.contoso.com`.

Defining the delegation is simple enough:

`sub.example.com. IN NS ns1.contoso.com.`

That should be enough by itself, but I could also define a glue record for it:

`ns1.contoso.com. IN A 203.0.113.1`

This would cause my nameserver to include `203.0.113.1` in the referrals for `ns1.contoso.com` as glue. My nameservers aren't *responsible* for contoso.com, and no sane nameserver on the internet is going to store that glue record in cache.

What they *will* do is assume that I want `203.0.113.1` to be queried if `ns1.contoso.com` is not currently in cache. This is fine...until the admins for contoso.com change the IP address of `ns1.contoso.com`. *My* glue would be wrong, and in many cases this referral would break.

Comment: As mentioned in this answer, I've noticed that several TLDs (e.g. COM, NET) provide glue records for nameservers present in other TLDs, as an optimization strategy. It is unclear to me who and how these are created and updated.
To give an example: "dig ns MISSERENDIPITY.COM @g.gtld-servers.net." returns a glue record for its nameserver DNS.TECHNORAIL.COM. However, the authoritative nameserver for TECHNORAIL.COM is ARUDNS1.ARUBA.IT. How does COM know (and update) that glue record, when it comes from a nameserver associated to the IT zone?

Comment: My practical experience doesn't extend into the TLD registries, unfortunately. Maybe @Alnitak or Håkan could chime in here?

Comment: Pinging @HåkanLindqvist in a separate comment since only one notification is allowed per comment.

Comment: @Thomas it looks like the Verisign name servers are applying an optimisation such that if _any_ domain name contained in their servers has (sibling) glue for "dns.techorail.com" they'll serve it (i.e. there's a "host record" for that server name).  Note how they _don't_ return glue for "dns4.arubadns.cz." but only for the .net and .com servers.  Now, whether that glue is correct is another matter - I know some VRSN folks I can ask...

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, you are right. So my question is: how does VRSN obtain glue for "DNS.TECHNORAIL.COM", when that domain's nameservers are all under the ".IT" tld. (Note that my question involves going one step further down the chain from the initial MISSERENDIPITY.COM  lookup: "dig ns MISSERENDIPITY.COM @g.gtld-servers.net." --> DNS1.TECHNORAIL.COM --> "dig ns TECHNORAIL.COM @g.gtld-servers.net." --> all .it domains)

Comment: @Thomas someone, at some point (probably using "EPP") created "host records" for "dns.technorail.com", and provided the IP address.   Most likely hypothesis is that at that time the DNS for technorail.com was _also_ at those servers, before it moved to the aruba.it domain, hence the requirement for the glue records.  I suspect that the NS records changed, but they didn't remove the host records.

Comment: @Alnitak I understand what you're saying. However, I see glue records every time I encounter this situation. While it is possible that your hypothetical scenario enfolded with all my observations, I do think there could be a more clever automated optimization process at play?
Some more examples:
// "dig ns RYNYOPDXPD.COM @g.gtld-servers.net" --> DDNS.CHANGE-D.NET (glue given) --> "dig ns CHANGE-D.NET @g.gtld-servers.net" --> all .NE.JP domains
// "dig ns DUO-HOZA.COM @g.gtld-servers.net" --> NS1.AMENWORLD.COM (glue given) --> "dig ns AMENWORLD.COM @g.gtld-servers.net" --> all .FR domains.

Comment: Host records are typically objects in an EPP based registry (there are exceptions), so they would need to be explicitely deleted if not used anymore (deletion is not possible if they are still tied to some domains).

Answer (score 3):

You should be careful to not confuse glue records with additional section records.  While it is true that glue records are placed in the additional section, not all additional records are glue.

In your example with `novanext.com`, you're seeing additional records for `ns1` and `ns2.net4india.com`.  This happens because the .com zone happens to have A records for those name servers, but strictly speaking this is not glue.  It is in included in the additional section as an optimization, to save a second lookup.

Note that glue data is not considered to be authoritative.  If you try querying the .com name servers for a glue record, you'll get back a referral and you won't get the glue record in the answer section.  This is what's happening in the case of `misserendipity.com` and `dns.technorail.com` per one of the comments above.  There is a host/glue record for `dns.technorail.com` but you can't see it by querying for it directly because you get the referral instead.  Probably this host/glue record is no longer strictly necessary, but since it is there it is included in referrals that reference it.

.com and .net didn't always work this way.  It was necessary to change their behavior before they were signed with DNSSEC.  This [NANOG post](http://mailman.nanog.org/pipermail/nanog/2010-January/016924.html)
explains the change.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Those are some useful insights. One thing remains unclear to me: if the authoritative nameserver for technorail.com (which is arudns1.aruba.it) decides to change the A record of dns.technorail.com in its own zone file, how will this change be propagated to the COM zone file? Wouldn't that host record for dns.technorail.com in the COM zone file remain stagnant without any explicit EPP commands coming from technorail.com's registrar? Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas there's no automated mechanism for a change to that `A` record to update the host record in the `.com` zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask a root nameserver for the `NS` record of `airbnb.in`, it won't know.  That's not the job of the root nameservers.  The root nameservers will just refer you to the nameservers for the `.in` registry.

```
$  dig +trace +additional -t ns airbnb.in

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> +trace +additional -t ns airbnb.in
;; global options: +cmd
.           489327  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           489327  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
a.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  AAAA    2001:503:ba3e::2:30
b.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   192.228.79.201
b.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  AAAA    2001:500:84::b
c.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   192.33.4.12
c.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  AAAA    2001:500:2::c
d.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  AAAA    2001:500:2d::d
e.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   192.203.230.10
f.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  AAAA    2001:500:2f::f
g.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   192.112.36.4
h.root-servers.net. 30831   IN  A   128.63.2.53
;; Received 496 bytes from 10.20.206.2#53(10.20.206.2) in 38 ms

in.         172800  IN  NS  a2.in.afilias-nst.info.
in.         172800  IN  NS  b1.in.afilias-nst.in.
in.         172800  IN  NS  ns7.cdns.net.
in.         172800  IN  NS  a0.in.afilias-nst.info.
in.         172800  IN  NS  a1.in.afilias-nst.in.
in.         172800  IN  NS  c0.in.afilias-nst.info.
in.         172800  IN  NS  b2.in.afilias-nst.org.
in.         172800  IN  NS  b0.in.afilias-nst.org.
a0.in.afilias-nst.info. 172800  IN  A   199.7.87.1
a1.in.afilias-nst.in.   172800  IN  A   115.249.164.142
a2.in.afilias-nst.info. 172800  IN  A   199.249.117.1
b0.in.afilias-nst.org.  172800  IN  A   199.253.56.1
b1.in.afilias-nst.in.   172800  IN  A   125.19.40.90
b2.in.afilias-nst.org.  172800  IN  A   199.249.125.1
c0.in.afilias-nst.info. 172800  IN  A   199.253.57.1
ns7.cdns.net.       172800  IN  A   194.0.1.7
a0.in.afilias-nst.info. 172800  IN  AAAA    2001:500:29::1
a1.in.afilias-nst.in.   172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4528:fff:13::142
a2.in.afilias-nst.info. 172800  IN  AAAA    2001:500:45::1
b0.in.afilias-nst.org.  172800  IN  AAAA    2001:500:50::1
b1.in.afilias-nst.in.   172800  IN  AAAA    2404:a800:2:1e::19:90
;; Received 492 bytes from 192.228.79.201#53(b.root-servers.net) in 32 ms

airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns4.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns7.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns5.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns3.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns2.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns1.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns6.markmonitor.com.
;; Received 168 bytes from 199.253.57.1#53(c0.in.afilias-nst.info) in 70 ms

airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns2.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns7.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns5.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns1.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns3.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns6.markmonitor.com.
airbnb.in.      86400   IN  NS  ns4.markmonitor.com.
;; Received 168 bytes from 64.124.69.50#53(ns1.markmonitor.com) in 35 ms
```

Note that if you were to try to use, `a1.in.afilias-nst.in` or `b1.in.afilias-nst.in` as a nameserver for the `.in` TLD, you would *need* using a glue record.  Otherwise, there would be a chicken-and-egg problem.  The root nameservers responded with glue records for the other nameservers (e.g. ns7.cdns.net = 194.0.1.7) as a performance optimization, even though they aren't required.

The `airbnb.in` domain doesn't need glue records, since its nameservers are all in `.com`.

Comment: But `airbnb.in` domain has `glue` records as you can see my output which has `ADDITIONAL` section containing the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of the nameserver. I am referring [this](http://www.barryodonovan.com/2011/02/16/querying-for-dns-glue-records) document for verifying `glue` record.

Answer (score 0):

For a more recent way of answering, look now at the official document on DNS terminology, that is [RFC 8499](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499).

It defines glue records like this:

```
Glue records:  "...[Resource records] which are not part of the
  authoritative data [of the zone], and are address RRs for the
  [name] servers [in subzones].  These RRs are only necessary if the
  name server's name is 'below' the cut, and are only used as part
  of a referral response."  Without glue "we could be faced with the
  situation where the NS RRs tell us that in order to learn a name
  server's address, we should contact the server using the address
  we wish to learn."  (Quoted from [RFC1034], Section 4.2.1)

  A later definition is that glue "includes any record in a zone
  file that is not properly part of that zone, including nameserver
  records of delegated sub-zones (NS records), address records that
  accompany those NS records (A, AAAA, etc), and any other stray
  data that might appear."  (Quoted from [RFC2181], Section 5.4.1)
```